# How to scale an object so that when it equals 0 it will go to the next frame? AS3

Tags: function, actionscript-3, flash, scaling

Ok, I've got some script for the Alice in Wonderland scene were she is eating cake and drinking potion to be bigger and smaller. I have been able to link two buttons so that when eat_me is clicked she is made smaller and when drink_me is clicked she is made bigger.

What I want to achieve is for Alice to be given a number like 2 and when you click eat_me it goes down by 1 and when you click drink_me it goes up by 1. I then want AS3 to recognise when Alice is at 0 to then move to the next frame. I have some code but not too sure whether I am close or not.

```
      var alice_size:Number = 2;

      drink_me.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, resizeAlice);

      function resizeAlice(event:MouseEvent):void {
      sitting_alice.width =  sitting_alice.width * 2;
      sitting_alice.height =  sitting_alice.height * 2;
      {if (drink_me.hitTestObject(sitting_alice))
      alice_size = alice_size +1;}
      }

      eat_me.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, resizeAlice2);

      function resizeAlice2(event:MouseEvent):void {
      sitting_alice.width =  sitting_alice.width / 2;
      sitting_alice.height =  sitting_alice.height / 2;
      {if (eat_me.hitTestObject(sitting_alice))
      alice_size = alice_size -1;}
      }

     if (alice_size == 0){
 gotoAndStop (405)
     }
```

Comment: Why the curly brace in front of the ifs?

Answer (score 0):

Move `alice_size`'s declaration so that is a member of the current class.  I would advise doing the same for `resizeAlice()` and `resizeAlice2()`, though you don't have to do it for them.  Also `drink_me` and `eat_me` are listening for different types of events; make them both either listen for `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` or `MouseEvent.CLICK`.  I'm not sure why `hitTestObject()` is being used, but the reason may lie in other code you have.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is pretty close.

- The event you want is MOUSE_CLICK.
- Test for the less than zero condition when you are deciding whether or not to advance the frame -- so you don't 'pass' 0, and never get to the frame you want.
- Try to use more descriptive function names.
- Get rid of the hit test too, unless there is some other reason you need it there (I left it in).

My version of your code:

```
var alice_size:Number = 2;

drink_me.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICK, growAlice);

function growAlice(event:MouseEvent):void {
  sitting_alice.width *= 2;
  sitting_alice.height *= 2;
  if (drink_me.hitTestObject(sitting_alice)) {
    alice_size = alice_size +1;
  }
}

eat_me.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICK, shrinkAlice);

function shrinkAlice(event:MouseEvent):void {
  sitting_alice.width *= 0.5;
  sitting_alice.height *= 0.5;
  if (eat_me.hitTestObject(sitting_alice)){
    alice_size = alice_size -1;
  }
}

if (alice_size <= 0){
  gotoAndStop (405);
}
```